# Layers with same CRS not projecting correctly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In QGIS, I have multiple layers that are not lining up, despite the fact that I have enabled "on the fly" projection and clicked "Save As" to reproject specific layers to CRS EPSG: 26915 (NAD83/UTM zone 15N). I've also tried "Define Current Projection" from "Geometry Tools." No matter what I do, I can't seem to get layers to line up. The oddest part about it is that about half of my shapefiles line up in one part of the map, and the other half line up in a completely different part. All of the previous questions I have found on this topic have not helped me solve this issue, or I'm too dense to understand.

The layers I'm working with are a variety (polygon, point and line), as well as .shp and .kml.

Comment: I would guess you have a layer somewhere that is off in its projection, and 'on the fly' is a great way to expose errors in your data coordinate systems. I would take a stab at checking these individually, comparing to something you absolutely know is in the correct coordinate system (as a base dataset) and save out each layer in UTM Z 15... otherwise, what are you trying to reproject on the fly to?

Comment: Once you've identified which layers that don't have the correct coordinate system, look at their extents. If they're all grouped, they probably are using the same CRS. Maybe a neighboring UTM zone, or a state plane zone (US) or MTM zone (Canada) or they're in lat/lon. Look at the extents.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure which layers are right, install the QuickMapServices plugin, and add an OpenStreetMap background using EPSG:3857 as **project** CRS.

Once you sorted out the wrong ones, try to download them again from source. Or use `Set Layer CRS` to bring them back to the right position. `Save As...` would not work on them, because they would remain on the same spot on the Earth.